# ¿Cómo podría guardar esto en la base de datos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

Necesito guardar en una tabla llamada alergias las alergias que se pasa a los  input que genero con evento on clik.
el código jquey es el siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//aqui hago el contador para aumentarle valor al name de cada input q se genere.
contador = 0;
$(".alergia-boton").click(function(){
//este if es para q no me permita generar input vacios

 if($("#id_alergia_paciente").val().length <= 1){
      return false
 }
 else{
 let valor = $("#id_alergia_paciente").val();
 let html = $('#contenedor_alergia').html();
//este es el input q genero con cada click y le paso el valor del input principal q es #id alergia_paciente
html+=`<input type="text" name="alergia1[${contador++}]" value="${valor}">`;

        $('#contenedor_alergia').html(html);
        $('#id_alergia_paciente').val("");
      }
    });

});
```

al poner a funcionar el script me genera los input de esta manera 
código html:

```
<input type="text" name="alergia1[0]" value="abejas">
<input type="text" name="alergia1[1]" value="fresas">
<input type="text" name="alergia1[2]" value="nueces">
```

mi pregunta es : como podría guardar estos valores de los input en la tabla alergias? estoy trabajando con laravel y jquery

Comment: Mediante Ajax, busca algunos ejemplos en la web.

Comment: esq es el problema no debo usar ajax , lo tengo dentro de un <form> y debo enviarlo con el resto de datos de el formulario

Comment: Si no debes usar `Ajax`, ¿Por que usas `JQuery`? Manda todo mediante la acción `Post` de tu formulario y recibe los datos en tu controlador mediante `Request` y lo guardas en la `BD`.

Comment: lo que pasa es q genero con un click los input por eso uso jquey , entonces esos campos generados son los q necesito saber como recogerlos y guardarlos

Comment: ¿Ya tienes tus modelos definidos?

Comment: si ya los tengo lo que e notado es q a la hora de de darle al boton para hacer el submit no envia en el request los input q genero con el script y no se por que si el div q los aloja esta dentro del fom

Comment: Entonces comparte tus modelos y tu función en el controller para ver que está fallando.